# Calculate the mean time by row

Tags: r, dataframe, date, time, mean

I'm trying to calculate the average time of each rows in my dataframe and put the result in another daaframe in one column conting only the average time, but for each row I get the same result.

My dafaframe (df):

```
X      X2015.01.01    X2015.01.02       X2015.01.05        X2015.01.06
<time>      <time>         <time>             <time>           <time>
NA secs     NA secs    7.702222 hours   7.578889 hours  8.056667 hours  
NA secs     NA secs    6.682778 hours   6.664722 hours  6.567500 hours  
NA secs     NA secs    6.738056 hours   6.054722 hours  6.621667 hours  
NA secs     NA secs    9.473611 hours   NA hours        9.573889 hours
```

What I have tried:

```
df_2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=nrow(df)))
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  df_2$i<- mean(df[,i],na.rm = TRUE)
}

df_2

matrix.nrow...nrow.df.. mean
<lgl>                  <time>
NA                      7.708015 hours              
NA                      7.708015 hours          
NA                      7.708015 hours
```

df

```
df <- data.frame(structure(list(
  X = 
    structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
              class = "difftime", 
              units = "secs"), 
  
    X2015.01.01 =
    structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
              class = "difftime",
              units = "secs"), 
    X2015.01.02 = 
    structure(c(7.20833333333333, 8.10916666666667, 
    6.6925, 7.33833333333333),
    class = "difftime", 
    units = "hours"), 
  
    X2015.01.03 = 
    structure(c(7.578889, 6.664722, 
    6.054722 , NA_real_),
    class = "difftime", 
    units = "hours"),

    X2015.01.04 = 
    structure(c(8.056667 , 6.567500 , 
    6.621667  , 9.573889 ),
    class = "difftime", 
    units = "hours")

)))
```

Comment: You have missing values in your data-set: you need to add the argument `na.rm = TRUE` in `mean.Date` if you want the mean to be computed only on the non-missing dates.

Comment: I have add your correction in my code but the output remain the same

Comment: You're indexing the rows not the columns. The index should be df[,i]. Check that df_2 has indeed the dimensions you expect.

Comment: You are right it's working now ! But i get a date instead of I expected, does a equivalent of mean.Date exist for time ? like mean.Time

Comment: If you just use `mean` R will dispatch the appropriate method if it has one. If you use `mean.Date` then you override that dispatch and insist on a `Date`.

Comment: Thanks ! I tough we must specify the type for mean.

Comment: Could you re-post your data using output from `dput`. The table, which you have provided, is unnecessarily difficult to import.

Comment: I update my post. I should have done it from the begining you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out I could just simply convert the time to numeric and then use rowMeans

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
  df[i]<-lapply(df[i], as.numeric)
}

df$avg<-rowMeans(df,na.rm=TRUE)
```

If you want to put it in another dataframe.

```
df_2 <- data.frame(df$avg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting your columns to `duration` available within `lubridate` facilitates that calculation:

```
df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.duration(.x))) %>%
    mutate(totalDuration = rowSums(.[1:5], na.rm = TRUE),
           avgDurationSecs = totalDuration / 5,
           avgDurationHours = dhours(avgDurationSecs / (60*60))) %>%
    glimpse()
```

You will be also able to obtain further units by using `dhours` etc.